# Why am I getting a "Subscript is out of range" error?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that is within a `UserForm`, called near the end of a bunch of other processes in the main module, but when it reaches `Me.GPListBox.List(iterI, 0) = Split (CCGPValues(key), " - ")(0)` I get an error stating the subscript is out of range.

In the `Debug.Print` directly before the `For Each`, the console outputs "Jorge Cardona". This is the first piece of the split. `CCGPValues(key)` equals "Jorge Cardona - $207.31", but when it calls the same split within the GPListBox, it breaks. Why is this happening when it works via `Debug.print`?

```
    Dim key As Variant, iterI As Integer, iterX As Integer
    Debug.Print Split(CCGPValues(147), " - ")(0)
    For Each key1 In CCGPValues.Keys
            Me.GPListBox.AddItem
            Me.GPListBox.List(iterI, 0) = Split(CCGPValues(key), " - ")(0) 'Breaks here
            Me.GPListBox.List(iterI, 1) = Split(CCGPValues(key), " - ")(1)
            CCGPValuesCount = CCGPValuesCount + 1
            iterI = iterI + 1
    Next key1
```

Comment: Have you added Option Explciit to top of your module - try that - and ithen Debug | Compile - it might point to an error that is cause of Your error - maybe using key instead of key1. And I believe key1 is an object - not an integer

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `Split(CCGPValues(key), " - ")(0)` - what's the "(0)" on the end. I really advise you get it to compile and then come back with working code

Comment: @dbmitch that 0 is fine, its just the array item index. in case of a valid, intialized array that will return the first element. `Split("a-b", "-")(0)` returns`a`

Comment: @dbmitch Yes, I will add Option `Explicit` to the top, but they exact same `For Each` loop works within the module when removing values (it compares to another dictionary, if a match is found, they remove from both) and printing them in the console. I have no idea why it would not be working in this case. Both the variables and sub in the module are `Public`

Comment: @dbmitch Disregard. The error was a `List Property - invalid array index`, after implementing @cyboashu's answer the issue was resolved!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running loop on **`Key1`** in `For Each key1 In CCGPValues.Keys` and for the split part you are passing **`key`** in `= Split(CCGPValues(key), " - ")(0)`

So there is nothing to `split` and hence the resulting array is not initialized. Then from a blank array, you are trying to read first element. So the sub script error.

`Option Explicit` avoids these kind of headaches.

Comment: I feel so ridiculous for not seeing this at first! I had previously switched from `key` to `key1` because `key` is used in the module and I assumed it was causing it to break. I plan to implement Option Explicit in my code but I feel there is another instance (this is an evolving code from when I started learning vba a month ago) and I know my code contains variables that are not properly initialized. Is there a way to easily find these?

Comment: We all make mistakes, specially in the beginning:) Its the best way to learn. Just add Option Explicit in all code modules and in the VBE Debug --> Compile VBA project or Alt + D + L , till you get rid of all get errors. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html

Comment: I'm sorry to get ahead of myself, but it still bugs out! I will add in the original question what the error is and where it occurs via image. Please review

Comment: sure or may be a new question to keep it less clutters and more clear. Your choice.

Comment: Since the question is still the same (unresolved), I will leave it as the same question to avoid a duplicate, unanswered question. But thank you for the suggestion. In any other case, I would.

Comment: Never mind. The second error was on the same line, but it was a `List property - invalid property array` error because I was trying to reference to a row that did not exist yet. This did resolve my problem. Thanks again!